# Jmeter: Dynamic URL encrypted

Tags: url, dynamic, jmeter

I'm working on a test plan with `Jmeter`.
The issue is that I can't retrieve the `URL` link as he is managed dynamically.

The `URL` has the following format:

```
localhost\blablabla?PATHPARAM=qzflh%2FGJHBGDCV%GROPJHVFFFDDFGGCFD%JJYTGVFRTVFGGFF%JUYGBG
```

I already try to search the value of `PATHPARAM` in the previous requests to retrieve it using regular expression extractor but I didn't find it.

It seems that this `url` is generated inside a `javascript code` but the way to extract it is unknown for me, inside the `js` code I find the value : `var url = actionName + "?" + params ;`

Is that any way to catch the content or the var `url` in `Jmeter`, else have you any other solution to solve this issue with this `dynamic URL`.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: how JS code gets/builds `params`?

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 possible options:

1. If you are being redirected to this URL automatically (you might need to play with `Redirect Automatically` and `Follow Redirects` boxes in the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

   [image: JMeter Redirects]

   If this is the case - you should be able to get it using the following [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) configuration

   [image: JMeter Regular Expression for URL]
2. If you need to replicate the logic of this `param` variable calculation - you can attempt to do it using [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) which can execute arbitrary JavaScript code

   [image: JMeter JSR223 PreProcessor]